# How to change the bet of ether into bep-20 token?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens

The link of Betting Contract:https://github.com/laronlineworld/Voting-Betting-Smart-Contract/blob/main/Voting-Betting-Smart-Contract.sol

How to change the bet ether into token(BEP20)

```
 function betOnCandidate(bytes32 candidate) public payable  {
        require(bettingActive);
        require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
        require(validCandidate(candidate));
        betters.push(msg.sender);
        bets[candidate][msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
```

And also the reward into token

```
/* Function to close voting and handle payout. Can only be called by the owner. */
    function closeVoting() onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
        require(bettingActive);
        bytes32 winningCandidate = candidateList[getWinner()];

        // getting list of winners and losers
        // and the money lost by all losers
        address[] memory winners;
        uint256 numWinners = 0;
        uint256 numLosers = 0;
        uint256 surplus = 0;
        for (uint x = 0; x < betters.length; x++) {
            if (bets[winningCandidate][betters[x]] > 0) {
                winners[numWinners++] = betters[x];
            } else {
                surplus += bets[winningCandidate][betters[x]];
                numLosers++;
            }
        }

        // keeping 10% as service fee and distribute rest among the winners
        uint256 prize = surplus * 9 / 10;
        // calculate prize per winner
        prize = prize / numLosers;
        // distribute the prize to the winners alongwith the money they bet in
        for (x = 0; x < winners.length; x++) {
            winners[x].transfer(prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]);
        }
        // Close the betting period
        bettingActive = false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This requires you to have the IBEP20 (or IERC20, theyre the same) interface in your code
IBEP20 Token = IBEP20(InsertYourTokenAddressHere)
function betOnCandidate(bytes32 candidate, uint256 amount) public  {
    require(bettingActive);
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    Token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount) // requires allowance to be greater than 'amount'
    betters.push(msg.sender);
    bets[candidate][msg.sender] += amount;
}


/* Function to close voting and handle payout. Can only be called by the owner. */
//I strongly advise you use SafeMath to handle the calculations. 
function closeVoting() onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
    require(bettingActive);
    bytes32 winningCandidate = candidateList[getWinner()];

    // getting list of winners and losers
    // and the money lost by all losers
    address[] memory winners;
    uint256 numWinners = 0;
    uint256 numLosers = 0;
    uint256 surplus = 0;
    for (uint x = 0; x < betters.length; x++) {
        if (bets[winningCandidate][betters[x]] > 0) {
            winners[numWinners++] = betters[x];
        } else {
            surplus += bets[winningCandidate][betters[x]];
            numLosers++;
        }
    }

    // keeping 10% as service fee and distribute rest among the winners
    uint256 prize = surplus * 9 / 10;
    // calculate prize per winner
    prize = prize / numLosers; // NOTE : are you sure of this one? 
    // distribute the prize to the winners alongwith the money they bet in
    for (x = 0; x < winners.length; x++) {
        Token.transfer(winners[x], prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]);
    }
    // Close the betting period
    bettingActive = false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have an error here:Token.transfer(winners[x], prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]); its says, contracts/BettingVoting.sol:206:13: TypeError: Value transfer to a contract without a payable fallback function. Token.transfer(winners[x], prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]); ^------------^

contracts/BettingVoting.sol:206:13: TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1. Token.transfer(winners[x], prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]); ^--------------------------------------------------------------------^

Comment: did you add the IBEP20 interface to your code? basically whats happening is that your compiler is interpreting `Token.transfer(winners[x], prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]])` as 'transfer  "prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]" ether to address "token" ' instead of 'transfer "prize + bets[winningCandidate][winners[x]]" tokens to address "winners[x]" '. i wrote it only out of memory though so if a second pair of eyes could tell me if i got the syntax wrong that d be appreciated